# Should I ask company to further discuss pre-determined raise when I am about to quit my job

Tags: professionalism, quitting, raise

### Background

When I joined my company, we discussed that I will get a 10% raise when my probation period will end. It's ending at the end of this month. I am supposed to get a 10% raised salary from next month without any further discussion about it.

My work performance is exceptional and I got a very lower offer when I joined my company so even after the raise it's not a good salary for my experience level. Back then I was in a hurry because of some personal problems and it was my first job so I accepted their offer without any/much negotiation.

I am about to quit too (will take 1-2 months depending upon luck). It's confirmed because of the poor working condition and I am not going to change my mind even after any raise.

### Question

I want to invite a discussion and discuss my raise with them. Is it professional considering I may quit in next 30 days anyway and serve my notice period for 2-4 further weeks?

Reason why I want to do is:

1. Learn my self-worth: Knowing how much I am worth will help in negotiating for a new job.
2. Practice my negotiation skills
3. I also heard many companies ask for you current salary when offering a job and just add 10-20% to it. So I might be able to get an even higher salary thanks to the raise.

Only thing I am worried about is if it is considered professional or not?

Comment: It seems like there are some inconsistencies in your question. You mention "at your experience level" but then also state that this is your first job. Also, you mention that the increase is a guaranteed thing "without any further discussion." However, you want to go ask for it, in order to practice negotiation skills and learn your self worth? I don't understand how there will be any negotiation practice involved in a guaranteed raise, and you know what the number would be, so that addresses the self-worth question.

Comment: Are you planning to quit with or without another job lined up?

Comment: What is it that you want to discuss? Are you looking to negotiate a higher raise than the 10% you have been guaranteed?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question may be different depending on the country you live in and the working culture. But, in general, what you suggest to do **is not really professional**:

- Your self-worth is not a fixed amount, but rather depends on the person/company is judging you and the skills you are bringing to the table. The maximum raise you get in your current company is not going to tell you much about how other companies would perceive you in the future (but rather about what's the financial situation of your department and how interested are in retaining you).
- If you are 100% you will leave anyway in 1-2 months, then the raise is going to have little effect in your finances - and it will likely annoy your managers when they find out that you did it only to be able to present a higher number to other prospective employers. You should only ask for a raise if there is a reasonable possibility of you staying (at least for some time).
- You don't need to reveal your current salary to new prospective employers (at least you should not be forced to). You can just refuse to provide a number, and instead **provide a salary range** that would make you happy. And here is where you should be using your negotiation skills (because the outcome of this negotiation will likely change your immediate future).

In summary: it is good that you are concerned about your self worth, and practicing your negotiation skills as much as possible is great. But you should only use them in situations were there is actually something worth to negotiate.

Comment: One thing you have not mentioned is that it would be much more compelling to show your current salary than citing a range you expect. Maybe it is not professional to ask for a raise if he is quitting, but it would bring a good advantage during interviews.

Comment: No, I don't think mentioning the current salary is a good idea: If it is too low, you are basically low-balling yourself. It it is too high, you'll be discarding yourself from the role even if you would have accepted it it for the same or a lower salary (this sometimes happens). And also, most companies tent to have a fixed budget, which means that it is unlikely they are going to pour more money in just because a candidate says so. Salaries should be set according to skills, experience & market demand for the role, no because of one's past employment history.

Comment: @carrdelling Yes in a ideal world. But a lot of companies do it. Also 2-3 interviews are never enough to judge anyone skill level for a recruiter.

Comment: Don't give a number or a range (a range is just giving the low end as a number). Make *them* give *you* a number.